# Why does a readLines (from url) result change after some iterations (in R)?

Tags: r, for-loop, url, readlines

My problem is that after some iterations in R the readLines() function doesn't extract the information needed anymore. And I don't know where this problem comes from.

I would like to scrape some player statistics from www.whoscored.com and loop over these players --> https://www.whoscored.com/Players/i

```
for (i in 1:20){
 sc_act <- readLines("https://www.whoscored.com/Players/101537", warn = FALSE)
    if (i == 1){
      sc <- sc_act
      j <- 0
    }
    if (sc == sc_act){
      j <- j + 1
    }
}
```

On the first iterations the result comes out as expected, it reads the sourcecode of the mentioned url into sc_act.
But then (after about 10 iterations)the result looks like this:

```
"<html style=\"height:100%\"><head><META NAME=\"ROBOTS\" CONTENT=\"NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW\"><meta name=\"format-detection\" content=\"telephone=no\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\"><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\"><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3\"></script></head><body style=\"margin:0px;height:100%\"><iframe src=\"/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=28&xinfo=9-5358627-0%200NNN%20RT%281545484419406%2074%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%2811%2c55645%2c0%29%20U2&incident_id=287001440012879521-35322777428756745&edet=12&cinfo=0b000000\" frameborder=0 width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" marginheight=\"0px\" marginwidth=\"0px\">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 287001440012879521-35322777428756745</iframe></body></html>"
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with `readLines()`, it is the website objecting to so many hits in quick succession

Comment: Thanks @RichardTelford. Do you know any kind of work around for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling too much times quickly the same url, I recommed you to read the book "Automated Data Collection with R". One simple way to fix your issue could be to waint some seconds between iterations.

```
for (i in 1:20){
 sc_act <- readLines("https://www.whoscored.com/Players/101537", warn = FALSE)
    if (i == 1){
      sc <- sc_act
      j <- 0
    }
    if (sc == sc_act){
      j <- j + 1
    }
time <- runif(n = 1, 3, 5)
Sys.sleep(time) # Wait between 3 and 5 seconds each iteration
}
```

Or maybe changing your user agent...

Comment: Thank your for this advice. Unfortunately the waiting time is not long enough. I will try to change the user agent. Will definitely have a look into the recommended book.